# Will ubuntu work with 2 in 1 asus ux360ca ultrabook?

Tags: ultrabook

Will ubuntu work with 2 in 1 asus ux360ca ultrabook?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is an entire section here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbook that may help.

***Note Bene*** : this was written before 17.10 therefore before Wayland, therefore is untested.

My advice is to create a bootable USB stick, stick it in, boot and test.